# How to train with SVM model using specific kernel parameters in R?

Tags: r, svm

How to train with SVM model using following kernel parameters in R?

linear, polynomial degree 2 & 3, 
radial with width {0.001,0.005,0.01,0.05,0.1,0.5,1,2}. 
Regularizing parameter by factors of ten from 10^-7 to 10^3 with each kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider [libsvm in R](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/R_example.html). The kernels can be selected through the [option parameters](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm).

Comment: Soroosh, I don't use R for programming. But if you decide to try libsvm, the link I showed you provided the examples on how to code in R. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found all the parameters except I don't know how to specify width of radial kernel. Do you have any idea how I can set this value?

Comment: Radial basis function is exp(-gamma*|u-v|^2) in libsvm. If you are talking about gamma, use -g gamma in the option, where gamma is the value you want to set.